# Only first 'click' firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a page which allows a user to 'nudge' someone to do something

I have the following html (it can appear many times but I'll show two for now)

```
<div class="nudgeHolder641">
    <a id="nudge" data-wl_id="641" data-nudge_for="415" data-nudge_from="63" href="#">Nudge</a>
</div>

<div class="nudgeHolder1172">
    <a id="nudge" data-wl_id="1172" data-nudge_for="415" data-nudge_from="63" href="#">Nudge</a>
</div>
```

I have the following code to action the click:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nudge").click(function() {

        var nudge_from = $( '#nudge' ).data( 'nudge_from' );
        var nudge_for = $( '#nudge' ).data( 'nudge_for' );
        var wl_id = $( '#nudge' ).data( 'wl_id' );

        var dataString = 'nudge_from='+ nudge_from + '&nudge_for=' + nudge_for + '&wl_id=' + wl_id;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/pages/includes/ajax/nudge.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {

                $('.nudgeHolder'+wl_id).html("<h3>Fantastic!</h3>")
                .append("<p>Nudge Sent!</p>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                  //$('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='/images/icons/check.png' />");
                });
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Only the first instance of the link fires when clicked though, when I click the second 'nudge' link nothing happens, the first one works as it should. If there is only one link shown on a page then it works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot have items with duplicate id's in a web page. The id must be unique.

Comment: Having multiple elements with the same id is your problem. In such cases, jquery will always choose the first element. Change `nudge` to a class and use `$('.nudge')` are you selector.

Comment: Also within the function, you might want to change your references from `$('#nudge')` to `$(this)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're binding to an ID, and an ID can only exist once in the DOM. Try changing it to the class:

```
<div class="nudgeHolder641">
    <a class="nudge" data-wl_id="641" data-nudge_for="415" data-nudge_from="63" href="#">Nudge</a>
</div>

<div class="nudgeHolder1172">
    <a class="nudge" data-wl_id="1172" data-nudge_for="415" data-nudge_from="63" href="#">Nudge</a>
</div>
```

And then bind using:

```
$(function(){
$(".nudge").click(function() {

    var nudge_from = $( this ).data( 'nudge_from' );
    var nudge_for = $( this ).data( 'nudge_for' );
    var wl_id = $( this ).data( 'wl_id' );

    var dataString = 'nudge_from='+ nudge_from + '&nudge_for=' + nudge_for + '&wl_id=' + wl_id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/pages/includes/ajax/nudge.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function() {

            $('.nudgeHolder'+wl_id).html("<h3>Fantastic!</h3>")
            .append("<p>Nudge Sent!</p>")
            .hide()
            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
              //$('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='/images/icons/check.png' />");
            });
        }
    });
return false;
});
```

});

Comment: He is overwriting his a.nudge with the ajax response. You should use on instead of click.

Comment: There's no evidence to suggest that he's re-creating the `.nudgeHolder* a` elements after updating from the AJAX request, so there's no need to use `on()` here...

Comment: Thank you, I guess the wait is to give everyone a fair crack at the whip!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having unique `div` classes, use them as ID on `a` tag. Like this:

```
<div class="nudge">
    <a id="nudgeHolder641" data-wl_id="641" data-nudge_for="415" data-nudge_from="63" href="#">Nudge</a>
</div>

<div class="nudge">
    <a id="nudgeHolder1172" data-wl_id="1172" data-nudge_for="415" data-nudge_from="63" href="#">Nudge</a>
</div>
```

And then, in jQuery; you need:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nudge a").click(function() {
```

---

#### Edit

Didn't notice that you were using `$('#nudge')` everywhere. As [ryadavilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1787888/ryadavilli) pointed out; replace `$('#nudge')` to `$(this)`.

Comment: You should probably mention that he'll need to update his `$('#nudge')` selectors inside the handler, too.